# Weird firefox related setTimeout issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, settimeout

This is the error, from the firefox JS console:

> [07:30:41.692] NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle] @ http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js:5

The issue occurs only in Firefox when a setTimeout was supposed to happen. You can see a live example of the issue in http://codemagic.gr .
Here is how to reproduce the issue: open codeMagic, press the "settings" icon, pick a different color scheme. In webkit browsers, the setTimeout's callback function will execute in 500ms which will change #left's background color to the same color as the .ace_gutter (so that the whole left side "fits"). In Firefox though since the setTimeout doesn't execute, the left side now looks "broken".

This is the link to the lines that were supposed to execute: https://github.com/varemenos/codemagic/blob/master/assets/js/main.js#L149-L176

Comment: Can you post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: This line is probably the culprit: `$("#console-editor").css("color", $(this).css("color"));`... `this` refers to `window`. What do you wanted it to refer to?

Comment: @FelixKling, you are right! I used to have that inside the `.each` function so it was targeting `.ace_gutter`. Please add this as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: The link to the code is broken. Don't link, provide the MCVE in your question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to have `$("#console-editor").css("color", $(this).css("color"));` inside the .each function, from few lines above, so the `this` part was targeting .ace_gutter.

When using the `this` keyword inside setTimeout, you are actually referring to `window` and not the `setTimeout` code's container